# Identity server cookie sliding expiration extends session lifetime only during the second half time of the expiration

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, identityserver4, asp.net-authentication

when using identityserver4 `SlidingExpiration` option, the session lifetime is extended but only if the request is more than halfway through the expiration window.
what is the reason behind it ? i would like the session to be extended at any time is it possible ?

Comment: I guess this is an optimization. No need to waste resources when you still have a valid session for long enough. What is your specific use case?

Comment: the thing is that the session would last longer if it's extended only during the second half time of expiration than if it's extended at any time.